# User Serializer is showing null in AJAX fetch but shows data in DRF

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, api, django-rest-framework

I have below the details of my serializer for the current user

**serializers.py**

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
      'id',
      'username',
      'email',
      'first_name',
      'last_name',
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(APIView):
  def get(self, request):
    serializer = UserDetailSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^user/', accounts_views.UserViewSet.as_view()),
]
```

going to *http://localhost:8000/user/* shows the proper json/api data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "stormadmin",
    "email": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": ""
}
```

but when I try to use ajax to fetch the data:

```
  async getUser() {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000'+'/user/');
    const resData = await response.json();
    return resData;
  }
```

I get this instead:

```
{id: null, username: ""}
```

My question is, how do I get the data I want with an AJAX call? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried with the same domain name - `http://localhost:8000/user/`? Django uses cookies to get the user and the cookie is tied to the domain name

Comment: Wow. That actually worked *facepalm* please post as answer so I can mark you as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same domain name - `http://localhost:8000/user/`

Django uses cookies to get the user and the cookie is tied to the domain name